# speed up my console setup

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, xterm

I work on different branches of a big software project.

For each branch I have a gnome-terminal with four tabs open:

- main shell to execute build commands in various modules (mvn)
- ./bin folder to re/launch the app-server
- tail -F sysout
- tail -F another log4j-Logfile

This setup works quite well in the environment I'm working in.

But getting to that setup I need to

- start terminal
- cd to branch
- open three other tabs
- cd to respecitve folders
- launch tail

This is quite annoying and takes too long.

How can I speed it up ?

I know there are better and perhaps scriptable tools (xterm, screen and the like)

Comment: Hey! I'm not sure about opening a new tab, but you create a bash script and have something like in it: gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cd /var/log/apache2; tail -f error.log; exec bash' You could open 4 terminals(build commands, bin folder, tailing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this SO Q about open a new tab [Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line)

Then I would suggest that you implement a couple of bash-functions in your .bashrc file for the various operations and glue them together.

`screen` is an option as well, start screen and set up your environment, when you are happy use the "session" feature in screen, see this [link](http://log.bthomson.com/2009/06/saving-your-sessions-with-gnu-screen.html)