# Sending different commands to different terminals

Tags: bash, terminal, command, gnome-terminal

I need to run 3 different programs at different 'computers'. These computers are open in three different tabs in a terminal. How do I make a bash/python/?? script which can send three different commands to three different tabs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean 'computers'? Is it a `ssh` connections or what?

Comment: @dmitry.malikov Yes. computers means ssh connection to a remote host

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** To the comments:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'ls *; echo hello world; ssh user@remote -XCt xterm'"
```

Note that this allows you to easily embed environment variables as well:

```
MESSAGE="goobye"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo $MESSAGE'"
```

---

I'd use GNU screen:

```
screen -DRS mysession # starts the session with a given name
screen command1       # start the commands
screen command2
screen command3
```

Now there are numerous options to show many or all windows at once, to monitor for activity, to log a window's output, whatnot. You can even detach a session and reconnect to it, so if you leave your desktop, you can come back to your session by logging in to your PC using e.g. ssh, and just typing

```
screen -DRS mysession
```

again: you'll be back where you were, all three windows still active

**Edit** Oh, and since you asked:

```
screen -xS mysession
```

will view/share the same session (named `mysession`) whithout detaching the other terminal. This makes it possible for you to share screens remotely, or show separate screens of the session in differen Xterm/gnome-terminals etc.

---

Some keybindings:

- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> next screen
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> split horizontally
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> split vertically
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> focus to next visible window
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> detach (reattach with `screen -DR`)

Many many more features...

- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> feature help

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, My intention is to send multiple commands which will run on multiple servers and I want to automate it (since I do it a lot). Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: No, I want to send different commands, e.g. A. run QEMU on Server1   B. run simplescalar on Server2 C. run M5 on Server3

Comment: Puppet looks to be a management tool. I am not sysadmin, just a user and want to use those servers

Comment: Something like this is sufficient for me: gnome-terminal -e 'command "complex argument"'  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611542/opening-multiple-tabs-in-gnome-terminal-with-complex-commands-from-a-cycle     Only thing is that I need to issue commands, which have their arguments. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer. I need to use xterm -e ssh xyz1 to different terminals and that would do. Thanks for your timely help sehe.

Comment: Yes, what is your answer...eager to know