# bash passing strings to "gnome-terminal -e"

Tags: string, bash, escaping

this question looks like [Opening multiple tabs in gnome terminal with complex commands from a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611542/opening-multiple-tabs-in-gnome-terminal-with-complex-commands-from-a-cycle), but I am looking for a more generic solution.

I have a C program that calls a script "xvi" with arguments. Each argument is originally enclosed within quotes (''') and each quote in an argument is isolated and back-slashed (this format is a prerequisite) ex:

```
xvi 'a file' 'let'\''s try another'
```

The script xvi must launch gnome-terminal with "-e vim args"

With xterm instead of gnome-terminal, this is easy because xterm assumes that "-e" is the last argument and passes all the tail to the shell, so the following is OK:

```
exec /usr/bin/xterm -e /usr/bin/vim "$@"
```

For gnome-terminal, "-e" is an option among others and we need to 'package' the whole command line in one argument. This is what I have done, which is OK: Enclose each argument within double quotes(\"arg\") and backslash any double quote within an argument:

```
cmd="/usr/bin/vim"
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do
  arg=`echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\"/\\\"/g'`
  cmd="$cmd \"$arg\""
  shift
done
exec gnome-terminal --zoom=0.9 --disable-factory -e "$cmd"
```

Again, this works fine and I am nearly happy with that.

Question: Is there any nicer solution, avoiding the loop?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot robustly and reliably put a complicated command inside a shell string. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion about this. Can you use `--` or similar to tell `gnome-terminal` to stop processing arguments? Can you feed it the command with `"$@"` via standard input/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could probably finagle `printf '%q'` into doing the job:

```
exec gnome-terminal --zoom=0.9 --disable-factory -e "$(printf '%q ' "$@")"
```

Comment: This does not work. Even with a simple file with a space:
`9829 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh -c xvi 'File 1'`


`9830 ?        Sl     0:00 gnome-terminal --zoom=0.9 --disable-factory -e ''`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but recently I had a similar need and I created a bash script to launch multiple tabs and run different commands on each of them:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of commands to run in different tabs
commands=(
    'tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log'
    'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log'
    'tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log'
)

# Build final command with all the tabs to launch
set finalCommand=""
for (( i = 0; i < ${#commands[@]}; i++ )); do
    export finalCommand+="--tab -e 'bash -c \"${commands[$i]}\"' "
done

# Run the final command
eval "gnome-terminal "$finalCommand
```

You just need to add your commands in the array and execute.

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/rollbackpt/b4e17e2f4c23471973e122a50d591602