# How to save tab specific data in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, tabs

The [tabnames](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1678) plugin keeps a tab local variable `t:tab_name` for the tab label. Unfortunately, `mksession` does not appear to save tab specific variables. What options do I have for saving this data, as I will need it to later (manually) load the tab names. Here's what I have so far:

1. Update `sessionoptions` to save tab data (is this possible?)
2. Find some `SessionSavePre` event to traverse all tabs and make a global list of tab names `g:tab_names` (does such an event exist?)
3. Update a global tab names list `g:tab_names` every time tabs are added or removed (I would rather not do this as it involves shifting previous entries around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496444/saving-tab-names-and-conqueshells-along-with-vim-sessions). What I did was set up a helper Python script which went through the file and looked for `tabedit` commands. Once found, it would append all necessary tab data after that command. The caveat is that you can't write/load complex objects like lists, and that the first tab is actually loaded as a window (via `edit`) and not as a tab.

I then made a mapping like so to make sure I always used my helper script when saving sessions.

```
nnoremap <leader>mks :call MakeFullSession()<CR>
```