# Open a program in new terminal tab using shell script

Tags: shell

This is a small shell script i wrote .

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "optirun yarpserver" &
sleep 6
x-terminal-emulator -e "optirun iCub_SIM" &
sleep 60
x-terminal-emulator -e "optirun simCartesianControl" &
sleep 30
x-terminal-emulator -e "optirun iKinCartesianSolver --context simCartesianControl/conf --part left_arm" &
```

What this does is , opens a new terminal for each program . What i want to do is open new terminal tab instead of a terminal . How should i go about doing this ?

Comment: You can do it in gnome-terminal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line

Comment: I can't seem to understand the solution from the answers to that question , how can i do this on this script . can you please quickly elaborate ?

Comment: I was thinking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2164621/745924) answer. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/3914197).

Comment: Works like a charm thanks :) , But only one problem i cannot see the first command which opens the yarpserver . it gets open as the other programs are able to connect to it but i can't see it . All the other 3 open in tabs.

Comment: This depends on terminal emulators.  (Some emulators do not support tabs!)

Answer (score 2):

This thread is really old but if someone comes here, I leave a bash script that I created to launch multiple tabs to run different commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of commands to run in different tabs
commands=(
    'tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log'
    'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log'
    'tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log'
)

# Build final command with all the tabs to launch
set finalCommand=""
for (( i = 0; i < ${#commands[@]}; i++ )); do
    export finalCommand+="--tab -e 'bash -c \"${commands[$i]}\"' "
done

# Run the final command
eval "gnome-terminal "$finalCommand
```

Just add the commands in the array and execute.

Source: http://joaoperibeiro.com/command-line-script-to-launch-multiple-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use **tmux** to do the job. Here just a quick example and a step by step explanation to it. Here I use only vertical splits which may be confusing you should read into the tmux manpage to see how to **select-panes**.

- First create a new tmux session in detached mode
- Then send the appropriate command to launch your first program
- Create a new vertical Split
- Send appropriate command to launch your second program
- and so on ...

```
tmux new-session -d -s foo
tmux send-keys -t foo 'optirun yarpserver' Enter
tmux split-window -v -t foo
tmux send-keys -t foo 'optirun iCub_SIM' Enter
tmux split-window -v -t foo
tmux send-keys -t foo 'optirun simCartesianControl' Enter
tmux split-window -v -t foo
tmux send-keys -t foo 'optirun iKinCartesianSolver --context simCartesianControl/conf --part left_arm' Enter
```

Hope this helps you.