# gnome-terminal new tab with alias as command to execute

Tags: linux, alias, gnome-terminal

I've created an alias in `.bashrc` file as follows

```
alias myproject = 'cd ~/Desktop/myproject'
```

After saving the file when I restart my terminal, typing in `myproject` takes me to the project directory but when I try to use the alias as a command argument to a new `gnome-terminal` tab it throws an error,

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "myproject"
```

throws the error

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "myproject" (No such file or directory)
```

What is wrong with this ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this ?

Comment: FWIW, on Mac you could write a osascript to open a terminal & automate some tasks.

Answer (score 3):

When a bash shell is started, per default `bash` executes the commands specified in `.bashrc`. This is how your shell knows your `alias`es.

Now your idea does not work because `gnome-terminal` never sees your `.bashrc` file.

You could try

`gnome-terminal --working-directory='<path-to-your-home-directory>/Desktop/myproject/`

Comment: My alias is sourcing the file and getting the same issue.

alias gratenv 'source /repo/${USER}/.grat.wd'

Failed to execute child process "source  setEnvironmentCommands" (No such file or directory)

"source /repo/${USER}/.grat.wd"

Do you know the root cause of it?

I also try to execute this command directly after starting the gnome-terminal but no success.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do something similar... possibly not exactly what you want, but:

```
alias startMyRailsProject='cd ~/Desktop/myproject; gnome-terminal --tab --tab -e "rails s" --tab -e "rails c"; exit'
```

This: 
 - changes directory to where I want
 - starts a new gnome terminal (in the right directory from before)
 -  creates a 2nd tab and starts my rails server
 - creates a 3rd tab and starts my rails console
 - and then closes the original terminal window which I call it from.
It does what I need it to and saves a bunch of repetive keystrokes  :-)
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in getting some of it to work, I am missing my aliases, but I can run the program I want in the following way:

```
gnome-terminal --window --title="testtitle" -- $SHELL -c "<path to script/application>/<script/application> <arguments>;"
```

An example:

```
gnome-terminal --window --wait --title="testtitle" -- $SHELL -c "echo test;read -p \"press any key to exit\" -n 1 ;"
```