# Can Terminal be told to open new windows as tabs in the existing open terminal window?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

Terminal has tabs feature in Centos Linux Desktop
which is very nice.

But when i open new terminals they all get opened as

```
NEW WINDOW
```

not as tabs.

i need them to bring up the existing terminal window
and open themselves as new tabs.

this way everything is more organized.

Comment: What command you use to open a terminal window. Try `that_command --help` it probably has a switch to open just a new tab in the existing  terminal. And probably duplicate [Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal,
SHIFT + CTRL + T to open another tab in that same window

I not sure if that is what you want, but ya..

Answer (score 0):

Also, under edit->preferences, you can tell terminal whether to default to open with tabs or terminals.