# open a tab and running a script using gnome-terminal --tab option on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sudo, gnome-terminal

I am currently in my Project directory.

```
$ pwd

/home/karthik/Projects
```

I do the following from the cmdline.

```
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="/home/karthik/mininet" -e  "sudo ./my_topo.sh"
```

I expect the above command to do the following

```
1) open a tab 
2) go to working directory `/home/karthik/mininet`
3) execute the script `my_topo.sh`
```

Instead it seems to do the following.

```
1) open a terminal. 
2) go to working directory `/home/karthik/mininet`
3) execute the script `my_topo.sh`
```

Also on a related note,How do I open a tab with sudo privileges so that I don't have to type in my password?

I tried doing the following

```
WID= xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}'; xdotool windowfocus $WID; xdotool key ctrl+shift+t $WID
```

This does open a new tab but how do I execute the following commands in the new tab instead of the old one.

```
cd /home/karthik/mininet;
sudo ./my_topo.sh
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1188959/3076724

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your bash script:

```
   #!/bin/sh

   gnome-terminal -x sudo ./home/karthik/mininet/my_topo.sh
```