# How to make an alias for a keyboard shortcut/hotkey?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, alias, zsh

I'm trying to setup an alias in OS X that will be run by a keyboard shortcut or hotkey. Is this possible?

```
alias newtab = "command+t"
```

Comment: A keyboard shortcut will run a command. Just find out what command that is and use it as your alias.

Comment: @arco444 While somewhat true that isn't necessarily at the level the shell can deal with (i.e. an application internal shortcut isn't running a "command" the shell can execute).

Comment: @arco444 any thoughts on how I can determine what command is being run when a shortcut is run?

Comment: something like this? [Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line) ..... but in OS X

Comment: @Rich as Etan points out that really depends on what application you're trying to use it in... If the application allows you to configure hotkeys that might be the place to start

Answer (score 0):

to determine which command is run by a Zsh keybinding, you should use `describe-key-briefly`. Which IIRC in emacs mode is assigned to `^hk` (`control-H` and then `k`). So you would type `^Hk` and after that whichever keybinding you wish to inspect. Example `^hk ^r`

To see all your bindings, just call `bindkey` without any arguments.

[...]

Now to answer your original question. To bind a Zsh function to a (shell) key binding, you should define a function that does whatever you want (not an alias...)

```
function hello() { echo "hello... I am running..." }
zle -N hello
bindkey "^hh" hello
```

now when you type `^hh` you will run that function. See the manual for `zle` and `bindkey`.