# open new tab in current window using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, tabs

I am using centos Linux. I wanted to open a new tab in the current window terminal from a script file named 'myscript'. I use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID # line 5
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t #line 6
wmctrl -i -a $WID # line 7
```

referred from this link [Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line). I run the script in this way  `source myscript` and i get an error saying `Illegal variable name`. How to fix this ?
Note! I don't want to open new tabs in a new window.

Comment: What shell are you using? `csh` or `tcsh`?

Comment: @etan how can i know that  ?

Comment: What does `echo "$0"` say? What does `declare -p SHELL` say? I'm guessing the answers are `tcsh` or `csh` and `declare: Command not found.` which will indicate that you are using `tcsh`/`csh` and that script is for bash. If you run it as `./script.sh` it should work even from `tcsh` though but will not when run directly or sourced.

Comment: `echo "$0"` gives `/bin/tcsh` and `declare -p SHELL` gives `declare: Command not found.` running ./myscript gives:                                                          `./myscript: line 5: xdotool: command not found
./myscript: line 6: xdotool: command not found
./myscript: line 7: wmctrl: command not found`

Comment: That's `tcsh` then like I guessed. Do you have `xdotool` and `wmctrl` installed because it doesn't look like it. Those errors indicate running it like that got past the `Illegal variable name` problem you were having (because it ran with `/bin/bash` from the shebang line) but had trouble because the commands the script uses aren't available.

Comment: @Etan Is there a way to check if xdotool and wmctrl is installed ? If so how?

Comment: Those errors are pretty clear that they aren't. I don't know if those are packaged for CentOS in the default repositories. You might be able to find them in the EPEL repos or in IUS or assuming it isn't in either of those it might be in the nux desktop repository. See the [Repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) page for more info about these repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the $(*commands*) statement.
Try to use `` instead:

```
set WID=`xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}'`
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID
```

Comment: I got `xdotool: Command not found.
xdotool: Command not found.
wmctrl: Command not found.`

Comment: Yes, `csh`/`tcsh` supports the older backtick command substitution syntax so this will "fix" that problem. But using `tcsh` in the first place is already a "problem" as-is trying to use the wrong shell for the script.