# Open a new terminal tab and run a command inside, only after open tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, terminal, tabs

I'm trying to create a script to open a new tab at my rails project and run `rails s` inside this tab, to already start my server.

My command:

```
xfce4-terminal --tab --title="rails server" --working-directory="Documents/projects/rails_blog" --command="bash -c 'rails s';bash"
```

The new tab open at the correct directory.
But I always get this error:
`bash: rails: command not found`

I think that `rails s` is running before the new tab is opened

or `--command` tag expect only bash commands. I don't know

Why is that? And how can I solve this?

**I already try all this answers below:**
[from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu)
[stackoverflow - Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line)
[from stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158434/open-gnome-terminal-with-several-tabs-and-execute-a-few-commands-in-every-tab)
[from ask ubuntu - Open Terminal with multiple tabs and execute application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application)
[from ask ubuntu - How to open several Terminal Tabs in different folders (working directories)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102527/how-to-open-several-terminal-tabs-in-different-folders-working-directories)

Comment: have you tried `bin/rails server` instead.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry @jww but did you read the entire question? *"I'm trying to create a script"* ... So I will use this command at my `.sh` file. Shell is about programming, don't you think?

Answer (score 11):

The following technique work well with newer gnome-terminal.

(1) This opens a new terminal window and executes "ls"
     and leaves the terminal window open

```
gnome-terminal --title=newWindow \\
               -- bash -c "ls; bash"
```

(2) This opens a new tab within current gnome-terminal
and executes 'ls' in that tab.

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title=newTab \\
               -- bash -c "ls ;bash"
```

The above techniques work with
*GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2*
Please note that old gnome-terminal options -e --command
and -x are being deprecated in future releases.

The preferred way to execute a command after gnome-terminal
is opened is to have the command to be executed after the 
last empty -- option.  In the example above we execute bash
command which in turn takes a set of commands that get executed within that shell. The trailing bash is needed in the first option otherwise the window/tab will close.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) for this.  You would put this in the director and then run `tmuxinator start project` and it starts the session in tmux for you.

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/project.yml

name: project
root: ~/projects/some_path

windows:
  - server: bundle && bundle exec rake db:migrate && rails s
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look on that!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use iTerm2 for all my projects. And I run the below script which opens up multiple tabs in the same terminal window and executes the necessary commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm2"
set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
tell current session of newWindow
    write text "echo Hello Terminal 1"
end tell 

tell current window
create tab with default profile
tell current session 
    write text "echo Hello Terminal 2"
end tell
end tell

tell current window
create tab with default profile
tell current session 
    write text "echo Hello Terminal 3"
end tell
end tell

end tell'
```

You can modify the command inside "" as needed.